# Using a custom lidar in ROS

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, ros-melodic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i have a lidar called Litra LTME-02A from China. However, i can not find any package to support this kind. Can you help me to connect this lidar with ROS ? Or are there any packages supporting all kinds of lidar ?
This is the link of this product http://www.litratech.com/article/121/24.html ?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372614/using-a-custom-lidar-in-ros/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2021-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Their are no generic packages for such devices. It entirely depends on the type of interface provided with the sensor (ethernet, serial etc) and the configuration parameters/commands for querying and setting up the sensor.

If you already have a way of talking to the sensor (driver) and getting raw packets into your computer then you can write a ros wrapper around the manufacturer/vendor provided driver.

https://github.com/LitraTech/ltme01_driver.git i found this driver for ltme_01 module. perhaps you could try using this first

---

Originally posted by [asusrog](https://answers.ros.org/users/19474/asusrog/) with karma: 63 on 2021-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2021-03-02**:
Thank you so much !